# Spring Invalidate another user's session just after admin locks a user

Tags: spring-security, user-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to invalidate a spring security session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478188/is-it-possible-to-invalidate-a-spring-security-session)

Could you please help me with my problem?

We are using spring 3 and spring security.
Our problem is that we need invalidate another user's session immediately (or almost immediately) after admin locks a user in admin panel.
User could be logged in at that moment. Then the admin locks the user, and after the user tries to make any activity on server side by clicking some buttons, it will be redirected to login page and have to login again.

Is there something embedded in spring security to do so?
Maybe get somehow a logged users list, then mark particular session as invalid?

Comment: You can use the `SessionRegistry`. Check out my answer to [Is it possible to invalidate a spring security session?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478188/is-it-possible-to-invalidate-a-spring-security-session/).

Comment: Thank you. Seems that what I will have to do finally, since there is no any embedded features.