# How cancel a cookie in spring security?

Tags: java, cookies, spring-security, basic-authentication

i am using spring security for authentication and if i have 2 servers (server1, server2) using the same file war.

the **User A** make login in **server 1**, saving data on persistent_logins table. If the **user A** makes refresh on **server 2**, is automatically logged. This is correct but if the u**ser A (server1)** makes logout, the data of table persistent_logins is removed and the **user A(server 2)** when makes refresh, still connect.

What i can do to user **A(server 2)** change to logout mode?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how to catch the moment when you need to make user_A log out, you may consider using filters and clearing the current session.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // skip non-http requests
    if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    httpRequest.getSession().invalidate();
    ...
```

If you need to inject some beans using spring, you may have a look at [DelegatingFilterProxy](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html)

Comment: can you explain me better what i can do? i am new with spring

Comment: Of course. Create a class which implements Filter interface. Declare it in your web.xml. And that's actually all.

Comment: Similar to my answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478188/is-it-possible-to-invalidate-a-spring-security-session/8480164#8480164

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution update data on both server when user logout