# spring security - how to make another user log out

Tags: spring, spring-security

When I wish to remove a user from my application, I also want to log him out (as soon as he clicks on any link). I can clear my own security context by :

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
```

but how should I clear his security context ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478188/is-it-possible-to-invalidate-a-spring-security-session

Answer (score 1):

*SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);* will invalidate the current session.

The SecurityContextHolder.getContext() returns a session-scoped bean. So calling setAuthentication(null) will invalidate the **current user's session**.

So you can just call this from the controller when the user clicks on a link and his session will be invalidated.

Of course you probably don't want to scatter code through all of your controllers to do this. So then you can use a **filter** to do this instead.

In your filter you could keep a singleton bean with a list of all of the usernames you want to invalidate. Then you check the current session against the list and decide to invalidate or not.